# Successful jQuery Ajax call cannot be processed asynchronously

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have the below javascript code and I cannot get it to return to the .done handler unless I set async: false on the ajax call. If I don't include the async: false parameter on my ajax call, nothing happens on the client after the service returns.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#testButton').click(function () {
        TestConnection();
    });
});

function TestConnection() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:52180/api/Accounts/Test',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        alert("There was an error communicating with the Mojo-Store server.");
    });
}
```

My Html is very simple. As you can see, I'm referencing jQuery 3.1.1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ServerCommunication.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
                <button id="testButton">
</body>
</html>
```

In my Web API project I have a simple method:

```
public class AccountsController : ApiController
    {
        public AccountsController ()
        {
        }

        public bool Test()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I can see that the server is called but I never get the 'Success' message unless I have the async: false parameter. I'd like to remove that. What do I have to do to fix this issue?

Comment: Note, trailing comma following `async:false,`. Why is `json` tag included at Question? _"I never get the 'Success' message unless I have the async: false parameter"_ What occurs when `async:false` is not set at `$.ajax()` options?

Comment: I updated the question to have the correct syntax. When async:false is left off the ajax options then the server is called but the javascript does not execute the .done code

Comment: That shouldn't happen! Could you just try with `$.post or $.get`

Comment: Please create a dot net fiddle as it looks verrrry akward. https://dotnetfiddle.net/. You can always use something like `.always()` for debugging purposes. Maybe you can tell us what you receive there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to work with a callback function if you want to use the success and error of an ajax call. 
Ajax is asynchronous by default and will immediatly call the return function after it loads. When you add async:false, then the whole ajax call is no longer asynchronous and will be able to call the success and error.

Try something like this to keep working asycnhronous:

```
$(function () {
    $('#testButton').click(function () {
        TestConnection(Callback);
    });
});

function TestConnection(callbackfn) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:52180/api/Accounts/Test',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            callbackfn("Success");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            callbackfn("There was an error communicating with the Mojo-Store server.");
    });
}

function Callback(data) {
    alert(data);
 }
```

Comment: Wow. That seems to have worked. I don't think I understand why that difference mattered.